# Cannot install or update apps on LG G2x

Tags: internal-storage, ota-update, insufficient-memory, t-mobile-g2x, lg-p999

My signficant other and I each have a T-Mobile-branded LG G2X P999.  An over-the-air update was recently released that upgrades the OS from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4.  She got the OTA update; I have not received it yet (and, given this problem, will refuse it until a solution is found).  Since the update, she can no longer install or update apps.  She gets the error (when updating Google Maps, for instance):

> Error downloading "Maps".  There is insufficient space on the device.

This is happening even after uninstalling some apps (which can no longer be reinstalled due to the error.)  Internal storage has 248 MB used and 1.2 GB free.  The SD card has 603 MB used and 4.6 GB free.

[Some](http://support.t-mobile.com/thread/24893?tstart=0) [people](http://support.t-mobile.com/message/131254#131254) on the T-Mobile support discussion board discuss a hard reset being a solution for this issue.  I would prefer to avoid that solution if possible, simply because it is a hassle and because we do not know what data she might end up losing.

How can she fix this issue?  Is there a way to fix it besides a hard reset?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my wife's phone (LG G2x P999). Unfortunately you're going to have to master reset....

If it doesn't work from the settings, then reset manually (hold power button and volume down till you see the Android guy then let go) after that your phone will be reset and the downloading issue will stop. Read through these steps prior to resetting to ensure you don't lose anything you don't wanna....hope this helped you

http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-2521
should be the 5th link down where it says preparing for master reset